# Puzzled by Xcode search path editor

Tags: xcode

Double clicking the text field for a search path in Xcode 5 brings up what seems to be an editor but it contains no apparent way of saving what has been changed. See the screen shot.

[image: Search Path 'Editor']

It has a little pointy hat that isn't shown as well.

If I move the box towards or away from the text field it represents it disappears and the changes disappear too. What the hell is this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly save it. Just click the + button, enter a path, then click anywhere outside of the popover to close and save it.

Comment: Good grief. Thank you.